# Why am I getting an error in my transfer function?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I'm trying to solve part b here, and my transfer function is coming out as $$\frac{-1.25s}{s^2 + 2.05s + 1}$$ instead of the given $$\frac{-1.25s}{s^2 + 1.6s + 1}$$. Since there were no initial conditions, I just transformed the capacitors to impedance \$1/s\$ and applied KCL at the node. What am I missing? My working is below as well, I can't see where the problem lies.

[image: Question]

[image: Working]

Comment: Congrats. Your math is right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis and final transfer function are correct. Must have been a typo in the exam model answer. You can double-check by doing TF = -(feedback Z)/(input Z).

Answer (score 0):

Your anylysis of the shown circuit is correct - however, I am afraid the redrawn CIRCUIT is not correct. The given transfer function belongs to a classical bandpass in Multi-Feedback topology (MFB) - and C1 must be connected to a node between R2 and c2. In this case, we get the term 1.6s in the denominator.